# Can I use a tenary operator when passing blade attribute to child component

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

pretty straigth forward. I would like to know if I can use tenary operators or null coalesce operators when I pass an attribute to a child component in blade.

For example

```
<x-filter :categories="{{ isset($categories) ? $categories : false }}" />
```

or

```
<x-filter :categories="{{ $categories ?? false }}" />
```

I have not been successful with this in laravel 8.
Am I having an error in syntax or is this just not possible?

Best Simon

Comment: did you try without the Blade echos, `{{ }}`?

Comment: no I haven't and it does the trick

Comment: @lagbox if you submit an answer i mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:

Use `{{ }}` OR `:` but not both of them

---

When you place a `:` before the attribute this means you are writing php within your double quotes, so as @lagbox mentioned in his comment just remove it. OR remove the colon and you are good to go, nothing fancy here.

Comment: thanks for the additional clarification - much appreciated

Comment: I mark this comment as solution - bc lagbox hasn't supplied a answer. Thank to you both