# Passing conditional disabled attribute to blade component with ternary operator

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Is there a way to conditionally pass a disabled attribute to a blade component? For example this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482634/can-i-use-a-tenary-operator-when-passing-blade-attribute-to-child-component) mention how to use the ternary operator to pass in the value of the attribute but the attribute name will be there regardless.

I am specifically trying to use the ternary operator in the blade component tag to add (or not add) the disabled attribute

template code:

```
<x-button {{!$aircraftType->canIslandBuild($island) ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
    Build
</x-button>
```

button component code:

```
<button {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'inline-flex']) }}>
    {{ $slot }}
</button>
```

The error involves adding `{{!$aircraftType->canIslandBuild($island) ? 'disabled' : ''}}` to the x-button tag.

The error that I'm getting is: syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file

Also if I change this `{{!$aircraftType->canIslandBuild($island) ? 'disabled' : ''}}` to `{{''}}` the same error happens so I'm curious if you can render strings from php code inside of the component tag header like you can anywhere else in a blade template. I know there are other ways to pass in data and conditionally add the disabled attribute by modifying the button component code but I would like to know if there is an easy solution here.

Comment: it would not be exactly correct to do what you want to do, the idea of having a component is to pass properties and have some logic do something, in this case you are over complicating trying to manage a state by passing or not a property (but having ugly blade due to that), you should be passing a `disabled` property and just do that inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Went with [matiaslauriti's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1998801/matiaslauriti) comment and decided to replace

```
{{!$aircraftType->canIslandBuild($island) ? 'disabled' : ''}}
```

with

```
:disabled="!$aircraftType->canIslandBuild($island)"
```

without changing anything else. It seems disabled="disabled" is included in the `$attributes` variable only when the value is true. This means that the button renders a `disabled="disabled"` only when `!$aircraftType->canIslandBuild($island)` is true and when it is false, no disabled is rendered on the final html for the button.